# Does linq and nhibernate return the same type of collection?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-sql, factory-pattern

If I design my db layer so I can swap it between a linq-to-sql or nhibernate implementation, I have to code against an interface.

This means the return type between both linq and nhibernate have to be the same i.e. List etc.

Is the list type the same?

Comment: IMO you are better off just picking one than abstracting the ORM away.

Answer (score 2):

If you encapsulate your database access, for example using the repository pattern, you could have the repositories implement a common interface and have the methods return the type you choose to use as return type, such as IEnumerable(T) or IList(T).

Since IList(T) implements IEnumerable(T) there is no problem in that direction. If you have an IEnumerable(T) you can use the ToList() extension method on IEnumerable(T) to get List(T). IQueryable(T) implements IEnumerable(T) to ToList() works fine in that case as well.

Something like this:

```
public interface IFooRepository
{
    IList<Foo> GetAll();
    // ...
}

public class NHibernateFooRepository : IFooRepository
{
    //...

    public IList<Foo> GetAll()
    {
        return Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Foo)).List<Foo>();
    }
}


public class LinqToSqlFooRepository : IFooRepository
{
    //...

    public IList<Foo> GetAll()
    {
        var foos = from Foo f in context.Foos select f;
        return foos.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, unless you'd want to use your db layer without LINQ query comprehensions (using the repository pattern), you should take a look at LINQ to NHibernate; in that case, you'd pretty much code against `IQueryable<T>` results, which should translate most of the time. (Though you should really test this upfront, because every provider is different in its LINQ support.)

However, 1-* relations on your entity types will probably not share the same type by default (it's usually `EntitySet<T>` in LINQ-to-SQL, and `IList<T>` in NHibernate), but if you can force both LINQ-to-SQL and NHibernate to use `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` for such relations, this should work as well.

If you're only after compile time compatibility, the distinction between the various collection types should not be much of a problem, as long as you stick to the generic ones. For instance, if your NHibernate mapping uses `IList<T>` and LINQ-to-SQL uses `EntitySet<T>`, just stick to the `IList<T>` methods, and you'll be safe.

Just watch out for lazy and eager loading differences of each framework.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate returns IList by default for collections, and a lot of linq expressions don't work on them, unfortunately. I'm not sure if there is a way of changing the NHibernate return type, as I haven't really looked into it.